# CSS Animation not firing with Knockout code on click of a button - and not dispatching click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I'm running into an issue with some Knockout code firing off a CSS3 animation. It works with one block of code, and doesn't on another. The idea is to show an animation when you add an item to the cart. The object in the code not working is coming up empty, where as the one working displays the product notification' div. The other issue is that  $('#cart-nav a.first').click(); is not getting dispatched when this action is performed. This is not working in either scenario.

Below is where the code works (for the animation), and another where it does not. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Working code where CSS3 Animation fires off when you add an item to the cart. The class 'rise' triggers the animation. One working block of code, the other not working, and the JS below that. Thank you

Works

```
<div class="thumbnail product-image medium">
    <div class="actions">
       <div class="product-notification-cont">
         <div class="product-notification"> Added to cart!</div>
       </div>
       <a href="#" class="button product-add-to-cart" data-bind="click:$root.addProductToCart.bind($data)">Add to Cart</a>
       <a href="#" class="button purple product-more-info" data-bind="click:$root.productShowMoreInfo.bind($data)">More Info</a>
    </div>
    <a href="" data-bind="attr:{href:'/#products/'+$data.id}">
       <img src="" data-bind="attr:{alt:$data.name, src:$root.servicePath+'products/'+$data.id+'/images/preview_image/medium?auth='+ax.JRR}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Doesn't work

```
  <div class="product-info" data-bind="visible:!(productLoading())">
      <h2 data-bind="text:product().name"></h2>
      <div class="product-description" data-bind="html:product().description">
      </div>
      <div class="product-notification-cont"> 
        <div class="product-notification"> Added to cart! </div>
      </div>   
      <button class="button" data-bind="click:addProductToCart.bind($data,productMoreInfo())">Add to Cart</button>

        <? } else { ?>
      <h3><?=l(23)?></h3>
    <? } ?>
  </div>
```

JS (console.log in there for debugging purposes)

```
 self.addProductToCart = function(data, event) {
      var $productNotification = $(event.target).prev().children('.product-notification');
      console.log($productNotification);
      ax.Cart.addCartItem({product_id:data.id, name:data.name, description:data.description});
     $('#cart-nav a.first').click();
     $productNotification.addClass('rise');

     $productNotification.on('animationend',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('rise');
    });
 };
```

Comment: Can you provide us a sample of your question on Jsfiddle ?

Comment: Why don't you use knockout `css` binding to add a class to DOM element since you are using knockout ?

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks. I would but there's a lot of other stuff happening behind the scenes, I can try to modify it to fit though. As far as using the css binding, that might work but in this scenario, I'd have to bind every button, something I tried to avoid. I do see though that it might be the best way b/c i'm using KO anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference I spot is this:

The working data-bind binds `$data` as `this`:

```
data-bind="click:$root.addProductToCart.bind($data)"
```

The not-working data-bind binds `$data` *and* the first argument of `addProductToCart`:

```
data-bind="click:addProductToCart.bind($data,productMoreInfo())"
```

Knockout's default click handler signature is:

```
function(data, event) { }
```

which matches your `addProductToCart` signature. The second (faulty) data-bind creates these parameters:

```
productMoreInfo(), $data, clickEvent
```

I.e.: it *adds* the additional parameters in `bind` *to the front of the arguments list*.

The quick solution would be to create a new event listener that handles the extra parameters. **However**, I'd strongly suggest changing your approach altogether. You should look in to `afterRender`, the `css` binding and custom bindings. Avoid DOM related jQuery code in your view models.

Comment: Appreciate your help!